# External Haml Variable

Tags: ruby, variables, haml, middleman

I created a layout with a variable inside.

layout.haml:

```
- title = "Example"
%title #{title}
```

It works perfect and gave me this:

```
<title>Example</title>
```

But, if I put this variable in a partial, it doesn't work

_vars.haml:

```
- title = "Example"
```

layout.haml:

```
=partial "vars"
%title #{title}
```

How can I define all the variables on an external document and make it work?

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do? Translation to other languages? Use I18n.

Comment: It's a template. I want to save all the strings on an external document, so I only need to replace it once.

Comment: I have found the solution, I must use global variables adding the "$" before the variable... Thank you all for the help

Comment: Global variables is a terrible solution. I'm sure there's a cleaner way. But if it solves your immediate problem, then there you go.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for content for:

layout.html.haml:

```
%title= yield(:title)
```

_my_partial.html.haml:

```
- content_for(:title) do
  Example
```

Comment: If I type = yield it brings me all the html content, because its a template. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: yield requires a param to be used as a named yield. Try adding yield(:title) instead. That will render <title>Example</title> in the sample above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could put your shared code in helper?

```
# application_helper.rb
def title
  @title ||= 'Example'
end
```

After that `title` helper could be used either in primary view or in partial. Notice that calculation of variable will be performed only once due to `||=`.